# Replacing Retina Display with non-Retina Display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My retina display in MacBook pro 2013 model broke. Part Number: 661-8153. Apple store said it will cost me $430 to get it replaced. I don't want to spend $430 on this old MacBook pro. What are my options? Can I instead put 2012 non-retina display or any other display to it which will cost me less? Right now, I removed the display assembly and connected it to an external monitor via HDMI port and using it like a desktop.

Comment: $430 is not a bad price, but if you're willing to do it yourself, you can get the [display preowned](https://amzn.to/2GGWh7T) for about $330.  The instructions are on [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Display+Assembly+Replacement/27666). Your other option is to see if you can find a water damaged unit with a good display (I've done this before) It may be "old" but it has a ton of life left in it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot unfortunately do that. The rest of the graphics hardware inside the MacBook Pro (up to and including the cables) are meant for that Retina display. You cannot just replace it with a non-Retina display (unless you connect it via the external ports with for example HDMI).